# Parsing ISO8601 date and time format in R

Tags: r, datetime

This should be quick -  we are parsing the following format in R:

2013-04-05T07:49:54-07:00

My current approach is

```
require(stringr) 
timenoT <- str_replace_all("2013-04-05T07:49:54-07:00", "T", " ") 
timep <- strptime(timenoT, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z", tz="UTC")
```

but it gives `NA`.

Comment: `%z` is the signed offset in hours, in the format `hhmm`, not `hh:mm`.

Comment: I see - best solution to replace the ":"?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`%z` is the signed offset in hours, in the format `hhmm`, not `hh:mm`.  Here's one way to remove the last `:`.

```
newstring <- gsub("(.*).(..)$","\\1\\2","2013-04-05T07:49:54-07:00")
(timep <- strptime(newstring, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z", tz="UTC"))
# [1] "2013-04-05 14:49:54 UTC"
```

Also note that you don't have to remove the `"T"`.

Comment: That seems like an overly general pattern. I would think something like this would be less prone to over-correct: `gsub("([+-]\\d\\d)(:)", "\\1", argvec)`

Comment: I need to do exactly the opposite!
How can I add `:` in the last part? For me, it always shows `+0200`, but I need `+02:00`.

Comment: @PeyM87: something like this should be close: `gsub("(.*)([+-][[:digit:]]{2})([[:digit:]]{2})$", "\\1\\2:\\3", x)`

Answer (score 1):

You don't the string replacement.

NA just means that the whole did not work, so do it pieces to build your expression:

```
R> strptime("2013-04-05T07:49:54-07:00", "%Y-%m-%d") 
[1] "2013-04-05"
R> strptime("2013-04-05T07:49:54-07:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M") 
[1] "2013-04-05 07:49:00"
R> strptime("2013-04-05T07:49:54-07:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
[1] "2013-04-05 07:49:54" 
R>
```

Also, for reasons I never fully understood -- but which probably reside with C library function underlying it, `%z` only works on output, not input.  So your NA mostly likely comes from your use of `%z`.

Comment: `%z` works on input, but the format is different.  `%Z` only works on output.

Comment: Ah, yes, thanks.  My solution still gets by without a regexp, or Hadley package.  So by our definition, I win.

Comment: It does all those things and, as an added bonus, provides the wrong answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

`strptime("2013-04-05 07:49:54-07:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC")` gives `2013-04-05 07:49:54 UTC`

Try

```
timep <- strptime(timenoT, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC")
```

Comment: That's incorrect, because the time isn't 7:49:54 UTC, it's 7 hours behind UTC.  So if you express it _in_ UTC, it will be 7 hours ahead of 7:49.54.