# Removing character strings in date in R

Tags: r, gsub, lubridate, stringr

$ date "20141013T000000", "20141209T000000", "20150225T000000", "20141209T000000"

I have this "date" variable in R dataframe. I want to clean this variable and remove "T000000" such that "20141013T000000" shows only "20141013" so I can then convert my date variable into it's proper date format.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing ISO8601 date and time format in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15838548/parsing-iso8601-date-and-time-format-in-r)

Comment: YOu can do `sub("T\\d+$", "", df1$date)`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to remove that, you can just do the date-conversion directly and specify the existing format:

```
as.Date("20141013T000000", "%Y%m%dT000000")
# [1] "2014-10-13"
```

Answer (score 2):

Or a `lubridate` solution:

```
data <- "20141013T000000"
library(lubridate)
as_datetime(date)
#[1] "2014-10-13 UTC"
```